# Generate equivalent HTML generated by Javascript (VueJS) on backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-side

I am asking this because I don't know if it's possible and don't know the terms to label this.

I have a VueJS crud app that grabs data from an API backend, and then renders it in great HTML.  Thanks JavaScript, and V8 since I use Chrome.

Now, I'd like to send someone an HTML email with a snippet of the table embedded.  That is a backend process.  But I obviously don't want to rewrite the VueJS HTML on the backend or in another place.

Is there any way, from the backend only, to call the VueJS coding and grab the HTML, or an innerHTML section, as if I'd called it on the front end?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is to use NodeJS and perform [Server Side Rendering](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/universal.html#data-reactivity-on-the-server)

This will require using the `render` method in VueJS which is different than what my CRUD application is written in.

Also as discussed in the link above, reactivity doesn't exist on the server side.

And in addition, the actual data that would be listed in a table needs to be pre-fetched.